# Springer Nature template - no citations & font issue

Tags: fonts, bibtex, citing, undefined, springernature

The Springer Nature template (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-nature-latex-template/gsvvftmrppwq) compiles on Overleaf, but when attempting to compile locally using pdflatex ➞ bibtex ➞ pdflatex × 2 in VSCode with MikTex, I get the warnings below. (The font & float & under/overfull issues are kinda okay, but the undefined citations not so much.) Thanks in advance!

```
"resource": "~/.miktex/texmfs/install/tex/latex/program/program.sty",
[
    "Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <16> not available (Font) size <17.28> substituted.",
    "Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <16> not available (Font) size <17.28> substituted.",
    "Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' in size <16> not available (Font) size <17.28> substituted.",
    "Font shape `U/rsfs/m/n' in size <16> not available (Font) size <17.28> substituted.",
]


"resource": "~/Desktop/template/sn-article.aux",
[
    "Size substitutions with differences (Font) up to 1.28pt have occurred.",
]

"resource": "~/Desktop/template/sn-article.tex",
[
    "`h' float specifier changed to `ht'.",
    "`h' float specifier changed to `ht'.",
    "There were undefined citations.",
    "Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/n' in size <8.43146> not available (Font) size <8> substituted.",
    "Font shape `OML/cmm/b/it' in size <8.43146> not available (Font) size <8> substituted.",
    "Font shape `OMS/cmsy/b/n' in size <8.43146> not available (Font) size <8> substituted.",
    "Font shape `U/rsfs/m/n' in size <8.43146> not available (Font) size <8> substituted.",
    "Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <8.43146> not available (Font) size <8> substituted.",
    "Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/n' in size <5.52061> not available (Font) size <6> substituted.",
    "Font shape `OML/cmm/b/it' in size <5.52061> not available (Font) size <6> substituted.",
    "Font shape `OMS/cmsy/b/n' in size <5.52061> not available (Font) size <6> substituted.",
    "Font shape `U/rsfs/m/n' in size <5.52061> not available (Font) size <6> substituted.",
    "Citation `bib1' on page 1 undefined.",
    "Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <4.015> not available (Font) size <5> substituted.",
    "Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' in size <4.015> not available (Font) size <5> substituted.",
    "Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' in size <4.015> not available (Font) size <5> substituted.",
    "Font shape `U/rsfs/m/n' in size <4.015> not available (Font) size <5> substituted.",
    "Citation `bib1' on page 8 undefined.",
    "Citation `bib2' on page 8 undefined.",
    "Citation `bib3' on page 8 undefined.",
    "Citation `bib4' on page 8 undefined.",
    "Citation `bib5' on page 8 undefined.",
    "Citation `bib6' on page 8 undefined.",
    "Citation `bib7' on page 8 undefined.",
    "Citation `bib8' on page 8 undefined.",
    "Citation `bib9' on page 8 undefined.",
    "Citation `bib10' on page 8 undefined.",
    "Citation `bib11' on page 8 undefined.",
    "Citation `bib12' on page 8 undefined.",
    "Difference (4) between bookmark levels is greater  (hyperref) than one, level fixed.",
    "Difference (3) between bookmark levels is greater  (hyperref) than one, level fixed.",
    "Underfull \\vbox (badness 10000)",
    "Underfull \\vbox (badness 10000)",
    "Overfull \\vbox (1.44444pt too high) in page 2",
    "Underfull \\vbox (badness 10000)",
    "Overfull \\vbox (1.44444pt too high) in page 3",
    "Underfull \\vbox (badness 10000)",
    "Overfull \\vbox (1.44444pt too high) in page 4",
    "Underfull \\vbox (badness 10000)",
    "Overfull \\vbox (1.44444pt too high) in page 5",
    "Underfull \\vbox (badness 10000)",
    "Overfull \\vbox (1.44444pt too high)",
    "Underfull \\vbox (badness 10000)",
    "Overfull \\vbox (1.44444pt too high) in page 7",
    "Underfull \\vbox (badness 10000)",
    "Overfull \\vbox (1.44444pt too high) in page 8",
    "Underfull \\vbox (badness 10000)",
    "Overfull \\vbox (1.44444pt too high) in page 9",
    "Underfull \\vbox (badness 10000)",
    "Overfull \\vbox (1.44444pt too high) in page 10",
    "Underfull \\vbox (badness 10000)",
    "Overfull \\vbox (1.44444pt too high) in page 11",
    "Underfull \\vbox (badness 10000)",
    "Overfull \\vbox (1.44444pt too high) in page 12",
    "Underfull \\hbox (badness 1107)",
    "Underfull \\hbox (badness 2245)",
    "Overfull \\hbox (7.4466pt too wide)",
    "Underfull \\hbox (badness 1082)",
    "Underfull \\hbox (badness 3281)",
    "Overfull \\hbox (8.2268pt too wide)",
    "Underfull \\hbox (badness 1460)",
    "Underfull \\hbox (badness 2781)",
    "Underfull \\hbox (badness 1259)",
    "Underfull \\hbox (badness 10000)",
    "Underfull \\hbox (badness 10000)",
]
```

Comment: Overleaf Support are quite good. What do they say? All those (font) messages indicate your local settings aren't mirroring Overleaf's settings. Without a minimal code example (MWE) to work on, there is only guesswork.

Comment: Bibtex should generate an `sn-article.blg` log file, that should indicate what went wrong, what does that say?

Comment: @Cicada For a MWE I can only provide the link to the actual template, as I have not done anything other than download & attempt to compile it... Also, since it does work on Overleaf, I'm not sure whether Overleaf support would be the place to ask this question?

Comment: @DaiBowen `sn-article.blg` is empty - however, `sn-article.log` contains the text in https://privfile.com/download.php?fid=63eaaccbaf00f-MTUzMTA=
Unsure whether it's of much use, though

Comment: @DanielvonEschwege the log file just sounds like `pdflatex` saying references were not found, probably due to `bibtex` not running or failing, absence of a `.blg` file suggests not running.  What happens if you run `bibtex sn-article` from a terminal?

Comment: @DaiBowen I get the folllowing response:
`bibtex sn-article`
`This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 23.1)`
`The top-level auxiliary file: sn-article.aux`
`The style file: sn-mathphys.bst`
`munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer`
`Aborted (core dumped)`

Comment: @DanielvonEschwege oh dear, that looks like a fault with MiKTeX. You could try updating and see if that resolves, how did you install MiKTeX? You appear to have a more recent version than the latest release on https://miktex.org/download

Comment: @DanielvonEschwege is there any news here? `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer` sounds like a straight-up error in the MiKTeX provided binaries, hopefully resolvable by updates.

Answer (score 0):

With the references, I think [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615138/unable-to-generate-bibliography-with-springer-latex-template) helps. Try checking [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58087/how-to-remove-the-warnings-font-shape-ot1-cmss-m-n-in-size-4-not-available) for the font size issue.